# Recursive feature elimination (RFE) with random forest

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-extraction, feature-selection, rfe

I want to use Recursive feature elimination (RFE) for feature selection on my datase using random forest. I came up with this code:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
# Create the RFE object and rank each pixel
clf_rf_3 = RandomForestClassifier()      
rfe = RFE(estimator=clf_rf_3, n_features_to_select=6, step=1)
rfe = rfe.fit(X_train, y_train)

print('Chosen best 5 feature by rfe:',X_train.columns[rfe.support_])
```

but after execution I got this error:

```
numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

and it is true because the X_train is a 'numpy.ndarray' and doesn't have columns.

what I want is that to find the name of the selected features. But most codes either give me the number of selected features or the relative column index.

I have tried to replace the code `X_train.columns[rfe.support_]` with `X_new.columns[rfe.support_]` (in which X_
new is a Dataframe contains all my features before I scale it and split it into train and test) and I got a result. But I'm not sure if I applied a right solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code snippet seems to expect a pandas dataframe. For a numpy array `X_train[:, rfe.support_]` should succeed.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got the results like this: "[[-5.46747407e-01 -1.90004232e-01 -4.24005257e-02 -9.58250139e-02 -3.98647600e-02 -3.05532134e-01]. However, I wanted to get features' labels for the result.